# What was the source of the concept "The Word was God " that John the Evangelist introduced in Jn 1: 1?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, gospel-of-john, philosophy, word-of-god

We read in John 1:1-2:

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.   He was in the beginning with God.

Clearly, John means The Son of God   for  “the Word who was with God”, as is evident from Vs 1:2.

No other Evangelist uses the concept of "The Word was God "; neither do we hear Jesus referring to himself as "The Word". Of course, he speaks of the words from the mouth of God, as in Matthew 4:4:

> But he answered and said, it is written, Man shall not live by bread alone, but by every word that proceedeth out of the mouth of God.

Now, there is a difference between `Word that proceeds from God' and` Word that was God'. Is it possible that John sourced the concept from an ancient Jewish text, or from Greek philosophy?

My question therefore is: **According to Catholic Church, what was the source of the concept "The Word was God " that John the Evangelist introduced in Jn 1: 1?**

Comment: See [Logos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logos) and [Philo's use of it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philo's_view_of_God).

Comment: Just for academic interest, John could have very well used the term `The Truth' in place of `The Word', and the Gospel would remain the same.  ``The Truth" would have also gone well with the statement of Jesus :  "I am the way, the truth and the life "(Jn 14:6)

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan I'm currently reading [Donald Carson's commentary](https://www.bestcommentaries.com/book/3809/0802836836-the-gospel-according-to-john-donald-a-carson) that has extensive discussion about *logos*.  He suggests that instead of *logos* association in Hellenistic context, the evangelist deliberately tried to allude to OT concepts corresponding to how the Hebrew word *dāḇār* appear verses describing God's activities in creation (Gn 1:3, Ps 33:6), revelation (Je 1:4, Is 9:8, Ez 33:7, Am 3:1,8), deliverance (Ps 107:20, Is 55:11), etc.

Comment: One avenue to answer this question is to search 2nd Temple literature whether there is any passage that link *logos* / *dāḇār* to God, either as "the Word was with God" (*ho Logos ēn pros ton Theon*) or "the Word was God" (*Theos ēn ho Logos*).

Comment: Thanks, GD. Hope you will soon come up with a considered view and answer. By the way, is it possible that  John used in a condensed form,  the words of God which he himself transcribed at Rev 22: 13 :  I am the Alpha and the Omega, the first and the last, the beginning and the end.” ?

Comment: Interestingly, almost all versions stick to the Greek letters Alpha and Omega . Some translations from Syriac use the letters Aleph and Tav which are from the Hebrew alphabet. If the role of those letters is only to symbolize the beginning and the end , the English versions would have used  `À' and  `Z'  .